# $C(X)$ is finite dimensional iff $X$ is finite

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, algebraic-topology

If $X$ is compact Hausdorff space and $C(X)$ is the set of all continuous complex valued functions on $X$,then prove that $C(X)$ is finite dimensional if and only if $X$ is finite.

My problem:If we suppose $X=\{x_1,x_2,...,x_n\}$ then how we can prove that $C(X)$ is spanned by the functions $e_i(x_j)=\delta_{ij}$ and $C(X)\cong \mathbb{C^n}$? And if we suppose $X$ is infinite then can I use the  solution ([When is the vector space of continuous functions on a compact Hausdorff space finite dimensional?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25983/vector-space-of-continuous-functions-on-compact-hausdorff-space/25991#25991)) by replacing $\mathbb{R}$ by   $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Once you observe that the Tietze extension theorem can be applied to a complex-valued function $f$ by applying it separately to the real part $\Re f$ and the imaginary part $\Im f$, which *are* real-valued, you can then safely go through Pete L. Clark's linked-to answer, which answers both parts of your question, and replace $\mathbb{R}$ by $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: As for why $C(\{x_1,\dotsc,x_n\})$ is spanned by $\{e_i\}$, it's basically the same argument as for why the dual basis to a basis of a finite-dimensional vector space $V$ actually yields a spanning set for the dual space $V^\ast$. In short, for any $f \in C(\{x_1,\dotsc,x_n\})$, just check that
$
 f = \sum_{j=1}^n f(x_j) e_j.
$

Comment: Yes, you can just replace $\mathbb R$ by $\mathbb C$.  (You don't really need to worry about real and imaginary parts.)  Hence this is essentially a duplicate.